# How to run a SimpleJobLauncher on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-batch

how do i configure intellij to run a Spring batch application.

I have tried the below things to make it run

for Main class i have

```
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
```

for VM options i have

```
 spring_batch_file.xml
```

but when I run it it throws the below error

> Error: Could not find or load main class spring_batch_file.xml

How do i run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running.

I had to change vm options to

```
-ea -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
```

and program arguments to use the xml file followed by the job id